# Input in Tkinter Background

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a simple program that takes two strings via the raw_input function and compares them. It tells me if they're identical or not via printing in the shell.

However, I want to add an interface to this simple program. I want the result to show up on a window, not the shell. I used Tkinter but the problem is that as soon as i run the program, the Tkinter window pops up (as it's supposed to) but now I cannot type in the shell. I have to click on the shell and only then I can type.

I want my code to work with a barcode scanner so i have to click on the shell and then start scanning. The simple version does work. But with the Tkinter interface, I first have to click on the shell and then only i can scan.

Is there a way around this? I want to be able to just run the setup and without doing anything, start scanning.

This is what I have in code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys

font = "Helvetica"

wnd = Tk()
wnd.title("Barcode Checker")
c = Canvas(wnd, width=800,height=600,background="grey")

green = PhotoImage(file = "green.gif")
blue = PhotoImage(file = "blue.gif")
red = PhotoImage(file = "red.gif")
yellow = PhotoImage(file = "yellow.gif")

#def keypress(e):
#    if e.keysym == "Escape":
#        wnd.destroy()

#wnd.bind_all("<Key>",keypress)

c.create_image(400,300,image = blue)

barcode = ''      

c.create_text(400,200, text = "Please scan the barcode\n you want to save", font =   (font,40))
c.pack()

def keypress(e):
    if e.keysym== "Escape":
        wnd.destroy()
        sys.exit()
wnd.bind_all("<Key>",keypress)


barcode = raw_input("Scan the MAIN item: ")

if barcode != '':
    c.create_text(400,320, text = "Barcode successfully scanned.",font = (font,35))
    c.create_image(400,300,image = yellow)
    c.create_text(400,350, text = "Barcode you have scanned: "+str(barcode),font = (font,30))
    c.create_text(400,200,text = "Please begin scanning.", font=(font,40))
    print "Barcode successfully scanned"

while True:
    barcode2 = raw_input("Scan the item you want to check: ")

    if barcode2== "quit":
        break

    if barcode2 == barcode:
        c.create_image(400,300,image = green)
        c.create_text(400,100, text = "Main Barcode: "+ str(barcode),font=(font,30))
        c.create_text(400,300, text = "New Barcode: "+ str(barcode2),font=(font,30))
        c.create_text(400,350, text = "The barcodes are identical", font=(font, 35))
        print "The barcodes are identical"

    if barcode2 != barcode:
        c.create_image(400,300,image = red)
        c.create_text(400,100, text = "Main Barcode: "+str(barcode),font=(font,30))
        c.create_text(400,300, text= "New Barcode: "+str(barcode2),font=(font,30))
        c.create_text(400,350, text = "The barcodes do not match", font=(font, 35))
        print "The barcode does NOT match"


c.pack()
wnd.destroy()
sys.exit()
wnd.mainloop()
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could also let Tkinter handle the keyboard input, see e.g. [Capturing keyboard events](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: or just take input in the Tkinter window itself & display the result using `Label`

Comment: If you show the code you may get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options:

1 - Complete Tkinter interface. Use `tkMessagebox.showinfo(`*`title`*`,`*`message`*`)`
to display the result and `tkSimpleDialog.askstring(`*`title`*`,`*`message`*`,`*`initialvalue=""`*`,`*`parent=None`*`)`

2 - create a function for the response. Use the following function:

```
def response():
    wnd = Tk()
    wnd.title("Barcode Checker")
    c = Canvas(wnd, width=800,height=600,background="grey")

    green = PhotoImage(file = "green.gif")
    blue = PhotoImage(file = "blue.gif")
    red = PhotoImage(file = "red.gif")
    yellow = PhotoImage(file = "yellow.gif")

    c.create_image(400,300,image = blue)
    c.create_text(400,200, text = "Please scan the barcode\n you want to save", font =   (font,40))
    c.pack()

    c.create_text(400,320, text = "Barcode successfully scanned.",font = (font,35))
    c.create_image(400,300,image = yellow)
    c.create_text(400,350, text = "Barcode you have scanned: "+str(barcode),font = (font,30))
    c.create_text(400,200,text = "Please begin scanning.", font=(font,40))
    print "Barcode successfully scanned"

    if barcode2 == barcode:
        c.create_image(400,300,image = green)
        c.create_text(400,100, text = "Main Barcode: "+ str(barcode),font=(font,30))
        c.create_text(400,300, text = "New Barcode: "+ str(barcode2),font=(font,30))
        c.create_text(400,350, text = "The barcodes are identical", font=(font, 35))
        print "The barcodes are identical"

    if barcode2 != barcode:
        c.create_image(400,300,image = red)
        c.create_text(400,100, text = "Main Barcode: "+str(barcode),font=(font,30))
        c.create_text(400,300, text= "New Barcode: "+str(barcode2),font=(font,30))
        c.create_text(400,350, text = "The barcodes do not match", font=(font, 35))
        print "The barcode does NOT match"

    c.pack()
    wnd.bind_all("<Key>", keypress)
    wnd.mainloop()
```